# Why does my plain JS loop not sum values to populate a new object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains an array of ~130 objects which again have a `field` called `orderProfit`.

 I now try to create a new object and populate it with the (chronological) sum of `orderProfit`.

**Input (sample figures):**

```
[{
    "trades": [
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderProfit": "100.000,00",
                [...]

        },
        },

        {
          "fields": {
                "orderProfit": "-500,00",
                [...]
        }
        },
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderProfit": "1.500,00",
                [...]
        }
        },

        [...]

}]
```

[image]

**Desired output as array:**

```
balanceByTrades = [100.000, 99.500, 101.000, ..., ]
```

**Current attempt:**

```
var balanceByTrades = [];
for (var i = 0; i < trades.length; i++) {
    trades[i].fields.orderProfit = parseFloat(trades[i].fields.orderProfit);
    // typeof returns number

    if (i == 0) {
        balanceByTrades[i] = trades[i].fields.orderProfit
    } else {
        balanceByTrades[i] = trades[i].fields.orderProfit + trades[i-1].fields.orderProfit
    }
}
```

**Which outputs**

```
balanceByTrades = [100.000,00, -500,00, 1.500,00]
```

So why it doesn't sum?

Comment: Your input object doesn't look valid - objects cannot have duplicate keys, can you fix it to show your real code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added a snippet of the real inputted data. I hope this helps to understand what I actually meant.

Comment: Then you have an array of objects, not just an object of objects

Comment: If you want to use decimals, you should use dots . as a separator, not comma's. that's why in your current output it says 100.00-,00, it stores 00 in a separate slot.

Comment: @Rumturf Ok so I will have to adjust the number formatting to make it sum correctly?

Comment: It might contribute to a solution. But i see in your snippet that you mark the 100000 correctly already

Comment: @Rumturf I just inplemented `Math.round` for testing purposes, still no sums in the output array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to parse a string to a number, don't use thousands separators, and to denote a decimal value, use a decimal point `.`

Remove all `.`s, and then replace the `,` with a `.`:

```js
const arr = [{
  "fields": {
    "orderProfit": "100.000,00",

  }
}, {

  "fields": {
    "orderProfit": "-500,00",
  }
}, {

  "fields": {
    "orderProfit": "1.500,00",
  }
}];

const orderProfits = arr.map(({ fields }) => fields.orderProfit);
let currentBalance = 0;
const balanceByTrades = orderProfits.map((profitStr) => {
  const num = Number(
    profitStr.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')
  );
  currentBalance += num;
  return currentBalance;
});
console.log(balanceByTrades);
```

Comment: This is superb.. Thank you so much!